# Serialize an object with an ArrayList inside

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, serialization, apache-axis

I have this object Vehicle :

```
public class Vehicle {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private String id;
    private int price;
    private transient ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();


    public Vehicle(){

    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public List<String> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public String[] getCommentsArray() {
        String[] commentsArray = new String[comments.size()];

        comments.toArray(commentsArray);

        return commentsArray;
    }
}
```

And i want to send it over the network with a web service. The problem is since that the vehicle object is composed by an ArrayList object, the server throw an exception (it does not happen when i remove the ArrayList field).
I suppose it's because the ArrayList fields isn't serializable.

I tried to make the Vehicle class serializble by following the intruction on this [page](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/?page=3). Wich means i tried to put the keyword transient for the comments field and implements the method wirteObject and readObject as follow.

```
private synchronized void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws java.
io.IOException {
stream.defaultWriteObject( );
stream.writeInt(elementData.length);
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
stream.writeObject(elementData[i]);
}
```

BUt it's still not working.

And here the WebService with the 2 methods i want to create :

```
public class VehicleDatabase {
    private HashMap<String, Vehicle> vehicles = new HashMap<>();

    public VehicleDatabase() {

    }



    //Not working because i use the vehicule wich is not serializable because of the ArrayList inside
    public boolean test1(Vehicle[] ve) {
        for(Vehicle v : ve) {

        }

        return true;
    }

    //Working
    public boolean test2() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here the exception the Apache TOmcat Servet is returning me when i want to create the WebService :

> GRAVE: Unable to deploy typemapping: {http://database}>test1Response
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: database.Test1Response  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.(WSDDService.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.(WSDDDocument.java:78)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)  at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> nov. 06, 2016 10:57:46 AM
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment  INFOS: Ignoring
>   non-fatal exception
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDNonFatalException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: database.Test1Response
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: database.Test1Response  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.(WSDDService.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.(WSDDDocument.java:78)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)  at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDNonFatalException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: database.Test1Response
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: database.Test1Response  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.(WSDDService.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.(WSDDDocument.java:78)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)  at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:561)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.(WSDDService.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.(WSDDDocument.java:78)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)  at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:561)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.(WSDDService.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.(WSDDDocument.java:78)
>     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.processWSDD(Admin.java:111)  at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.process(Admin.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.AdminService(Admin.java:65)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Your diagnostic is wrong, for several reasons. 1. ArrayList is Serializable. 2. Even is it wasn't, the field is transient, so Java serialization wouldn't serialize it. 3. web services don't use Java serialization anyway. I don't know much about axis, but your exception complains about a class named database.test1Response that can't be found. So I just guess you forgot to provide, generate or include that class inside your app. In general, your fields shouldbe of type List, not ArrayList.

Comment: If my diagnostic is wrong why this exception only happens when i add the ARrayList field in Vehicle ?

Comment: For another reason. If I knew, I would have posted an answer.

Comment: The things is that i don't have the class the exception is refereing too. I'm using an eclipse software to create the WebService. I only have a method that is named test1 in the VehicleDatabase class. Do you have more information on this ?

Comment: No, I don't have any. You should tag your question with axis.